# How can I run Stripe CLI through Docker to localhost

Tags: docker, stripe-payments

I can't seem to find an answer to this; I have consulted ChatGPT and the web for hours and it is driving me insane

I need to utilise the Stripe CLI in my development environment

Stripe CLI tests positive for a virus - NO WAY I can use this even if I wanted to, policy.

**TLDR: I just want to run a docker container with stripe CLI that forwards the requests to a local domain: example.local/stripe_endpoint.php which is located on the host machine**

I guess I also need to change the hosts file

Using ChatGPT for assistance, the best I have come up with is:

Dockerfile:
# Use the official Stripe CLI image as the base image
FROM stripe/stripe-cli:latest

```
# Set environment variables
ENV STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=...

# Copy the entrypoint script into the container
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

# Make the entrypoint script executable
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

# Set the entrypoint command
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  stripe_cli:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - my_bridge
    container_name: stripe_cli_container
    working_dir: /app

networks:
  my_bridge:
    driver: bridge
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
# Configure custom DNS resolution
echo '0.0.0.0 example.local' >> /etc/hosts

# Start the Stripe CLI with your desired command
/bin/sh -c "stripe listen --forward-to http://example.local/stripe_endpoint.php && tail -f /dev/null"
```

*0.0.0.0 = my local ip obfuscated for posting

This does allow me to login to stripe, but then the script exits, I don't know why as I though it doesn't exit if run from shell:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/issues/497#issuecomment-686558554

Yeah, so thats that - not sure why it is so difficult to do something so simple? I mean, Stripe is not a small company, you'd think they could get their CLI on virus whitelists...

Would really appreciate any pointers, many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "Stripe CLI tests positive for a virus"? Is your docker container deployed locally or on a remote server somewhere? In general, for anything other than local development, it is recommended to register a public webhook endpoint instead of using Stripe CLI to forward events.

Comment: be aware that if something contains a virus, even running it in docker might not be safe enough. at least, and maybe you already did, but if not: make sure you protect your network by only allowing outgoing container traffic to the internet but not to the local host machine or local network

Comment: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/issues/692
I don't believe it genuinely contains a virus, I imagine it is a false positive based on the way it works, but I cannot use it directly as a result
Without the CLI I can't think of a way to get this working - running it in docker is my only way really, but I hear what you are saying about virus in docker container

Comment: It is a local docker container, running on the same PC as the endpoint